# Hiding the Date field of an Object in JSP page of Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a property called createdOn in my java class. I want that to be hidden at the front end so that user will not be able to set it(I am setting its value at the back end). But when I use the below line of code in my JSP page, I am not able to post it to the controller(Data posting to the controller from JSP is syntactically incorrect).

```
<form:hidden path="createdOn"/>
```

In my java class it looks like:

```
public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn;
}
public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
}
```

Since I am using the same form for editing the fields, I have to use the createdOn field in JSP page (otherwise it will go as null).
I can solve this by converting the date formats to string and vice versa in setter and getter method. Is there any alternative solution for the same in the front end itself?

Comment: When data is edited and submitted to backend don't you load the data from database before updating with the new value? If you load the data the `createdOn` will have the original value.

Comment: Concerning the hidden field - it's not really hidden!  A user could easily do some browser debugging, intercept the POST, and change the createdOn value.  Not so funny story - JSP was used to collect some info and send an email when the server received the POST. Well, the JSP had the recipient email address as a hidden field so the server process would know where to send the email.  This was a public page.  Security scan discovered the flaw which basically allows anybody to intercept the POST, change the recipient hidden value, and use the server as a spam machine.

Comment: Hi W-S, I am able to load the data from database to my JSP page, but if I do not use the createdOn field anywhere in the front end, so it will become null when I post the modified data. So I am trying to hide field alone at the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem , please find my opinion , i hope it will work for your query.

```
<form:input class="hideinput" path="createdOn" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: Hi Komal, it did not work for me. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: this will work if you  want that to be hidden at the front end so that user will not be able to set it!